# Xamarin forms shared ZXingScannerPage KeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#, xamarin, qr-code, zxing

I have created a new xamarin project using shared code.

I have installed the **ZXing.Net.Mobile** and **ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms** nuget packages. I tried to follow a lots of tutorial but it keeps throwing exception when I call the scannerpage.

[image]

this is my code:

```
 private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var scan = new ZXingScannerPage();

            Navigation.PushAsync(scan);

            scan.OnScanResult += Scan_OnScanResult;
        }

        private void Scan_OnScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
        {
            if (result != null)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
                                               async () =>
                                                   {
                                                       await Navigation.PopAsync(true);
                                                       MyCode.Text = result.Text;
                                                   });
            }
        }
```

Any idea how to get it work on a new xamarin project?
I have checked the Camera in android manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code and let me know if it works? It's hard to say what might be the problem based on that exception message.

```
        try
        {
            var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
            scanPage.IsScanning = true;

            scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
            {
            // Stop scanning
            scanPage.IsScanning = false;

            // Pop the page and show the result
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    await Navigation.PopAsync(true);

                    await DisplayAlert("Scanned Code", result.Text, "OK");
                });
            };

            Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);
        }
        catch
        {
            // handle exception
        }
```

Comment: Thansk ,but finaly I found the solution. The problem is the Xamarin Live player. I don't know why, but if I plug in via usb it works, but if I use live player it throws me the error. I don't understand.